# SQL Max of a sum (two rows with same value)

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, I had a quiz with the question being to write a select query that returns the highest valued items (and only the highest).  So I have 2 tables one with the inventory of items, one with their prices of each items.  I had to sum the value of all the items and then return which items had the most value, and if any had the same to show both.

What I came up with works, but i'm fairly positive there's a simpler way to do that.  I was just wondering if someone could help me simplify my answer:

```
select a.item from
(select item , sum(price) as price from Inventory i
inner join prices p on p.item = i.item
group by item, price) a
where price= (select MAX(a.price) from
(select item , sum(price) as price from Inventory i
inner join prices p on p.item = i.item
group by item, price) a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write (using the HAVING function)

```
select i.item
from Inventory i
inner join prices p on p.item = i.item
group by i.item
having sum(price) = (SELECT MAX(sum_price) from (select SUM(price) OVER (PARTITION BY item) sum_price from prices) a);
```